# Question to first order PDE with Characteristics Method

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, problem-solving, linear-pde

We have the given problem

\begin{align} 
-2yu_{x} + u_{y} + 2yu &= 2y \tag 1 \\
u(1,y) &= 1 + e^{-1-2y^2} \tag 2
\end{align}

where $x > 0, y \in \mathbb{R^*}$. We can modify the formula $(1)$ to get

\begin{align}
-2yu_{x} + u_{y} &= 2y - 2yu \\
\implies -2yu_{x} + u_{y} &= 2y(1-u) \\
\implies -u_{x} + \frac{u_{y}}{2y} &= 1-u \\
\implies u_{x} - \frac{u_{y}}{2y} &= u-1
\end{align}

so our problem would be

\begin{align}
u_{x} - \frac{u_{y}}{2y} &= u-1 \tag 3 \\
u(1,y) &= 1 + e^{-1-2y^2} \tag 4
\end{align}

The method of characteristics gives

$$\dfrac{dx}{1} = -2y dy = \dfrac{du}{u-1}$$

---

**Edited** after @MatthewCassell suggestion

Now, we have

\begin{align}
\dfrac{dx}{1} =  -2y dy \implies 
 C_{1} &= y^2+x
\end{align}

and

\begin{align}
\dfrac{dx}{1} = \dfrac{du}{u-1} \implies u &= C_{2} e^x + 1 \\
\implies C_{2} &= \frac{u-1}{e^x}
\end{align}

The general solution of the PDE expressed in the form of implicit equation

$$C_2=G(C_1)$$

So $$u=e^x G(x+y^2)+1$$

Now, using the initial condition $u(1,y)=1+e^{-1-2y^2}$ gives

$$1+e^{-1-2y^2} = e G(1+y^2)+1 \implies G(1+y^2) = \frac{e^{-1-2y^2}}{e}$$

I get something strange (from what I've seen at least). Is this possible?

Comment: There is an error in your solution as written; it should be $$\frac{u}{e^{x}+1} = G(ye^{2x}) \implies u = (e^{x}+1) G(y e^{2x})$$

Comment: @MatthewCassell now is it correct? I have not seen a function like this before

Comment: Your ratios are wrong to begin with; it should be $$\frac{dx}{1} = \color{red}{-2y} dy = \frac{du}{u-1}$$ so that the first characteristic is given by $$x + y^{2} = C_{1}$$

Comment: @MatthewCassell I made the changes as you said to me, as you can see in my answer. But also it is not a familiar function.

Comment: From your last line you now have \begin{align} G(1 + y^{2}) &= \frac{e^{-1 - 2 y^{2}}}{e} \\ &= e^{-2 (1 + y^{2})} \\ \implies G(x + y^{2}) &= e^{-2 (x + y^{2})} \\ \implies u &= e^{x} e^{-2 (x + y^{2})} + 1 \\ &= e^{-x - 2y^{2}} + 1 \end{align} which you can check satisfies the PDE and boundary condition.

Comment: @MatthewCassell Thank you so much!

Comment: No worries. Now that you have a complete solution, you might want to write an answer below to your own question and and accept it, so that the system recognises that the question has been fulfilled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Solution***

\begin{align}
-2yu_{x} + u_{y} &= 2y - 2yu \\
\implies -2yu_{x} + u_{y} &= 2y(1-u) \\
\implies -u_{x} + \frac{u_{y}}{2y} &= 1-u \\
\implies u_{x} - \frac{u_{y}}{2y} &= u-1
\end{align}

so our problem would be

\begin{align}
u_{x} - \frac{u_{y}}{2y} &= u-1 \tag 3 \\
u(1,y) &= 1 + e^{-1-2y^2} \tag 4
\end{align}

The method of characteristics gives

$$\dfrac{dx}{1} = -2y dy = \dfrac{du}{u-1}$$

Now, we have

\begin{align}
\dfrac{dx}{1} =  -2y dy \implies 
 C_{1} &= y^2+x
\end{align}

and

\begin{align}
\dfrac{dx}{1} = \dfrac{du}{u-1} \implies u &= C_{2} e^x + 1 \\
\end{align}

The general solution of the PDE expressed in the form of implicit equation

$$C_2=G(C_1)$$

So $$u=e^x G(x+y^2)+1$$

Now, using the initial condition $u(1,y)=1+e^{-1-2y^2}$ gives

$$1+e^{-1-2y^2} = e G(1+y^2)+1 \implies G(1+y^2) = \frac{e^{-1-2y^2}}{e}$$

Then,
\begin{align}
G(1+y^2) &= e^{-2-2y^2}\\
&=e^{-2(1+y^2)}
\end{align}

So we can see that

\begin{align}
G(x+y^2) &= e^{-2(x+y^2)}\\
\implies u&=e^x \cdot e^{-2(x+y^2)} +1\\
&=e^{-x-2y^2} +1
\end{align}

which satisfies the PDE and boundary condition